# Multi level component inheritance in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, inheritance

I have a base component with some getters, component A which inherits base component and component B which inherits from component A. The problem is the getters defined in the base component can be accessed in the template of component A but not component B.
My question is does Angular support multi level component inheritance?

My Code

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit() { }

  constructor(injector: InJector) {}

  get name():string {
    return 'my name';
}
export class AComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
     super(injector)
  }
}
export class BComponent extends AComponent {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
     super(injector)
  }
}
```

name is accessible in the template of AComponent but its undefined in BComponent and I don't know why and would love someone explain to me whats going on.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your issue. I created a stackblitz for you and it works fine. Please check the HomeController. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example-r78t2v

Comment: I'll go over my code again.
Thanks